# So I've installed Signal Messenger on CentOS using Snap, now how do I start it?

Tags: gnome, desktop, centos-7, desktop-icons, snap

I have snap installed in my CentOS 7 installation. With it I have installed Signal Messenger. However no icon appears for the program and running `signal` at the terminal finds no application. How do I run a program that has no icon or link, or better still how can I create an icon or link?

**Update**

A new instance of the terminal can access it by running `signal-desktop`. Still, why is there no desktop icon and how could I add one?

Comment: Did you try with `sudo rpm -qa | grep signal` to see if it got properly installed?

Comment: I have just tried that and it doesn't show up in the rpm list. Yet as per my update, I can run it from the terminal.

Comment: For icon issue I think you can find an answer here (for Ubuntu but could work for CentOS) https://askubuntu.com/questions/800685/add-a-snap-icon-to-the-desktop-ubuntu-16-04#801422

Answer (score 1):

Most `snap` apps don't add a icon, in my experience, but it's easy enough to do.

To add a desktop icon, create a file such as this in the /usr/local/share/applications folder:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/path/to/executable
Name=Name of Application
```

The only required options are Exec (where you put the path of the Signal app, which you can find using `whereis signal-desktop`), Name (probaly Signal), Terminal (false— it's a graphical app), and Type (which should be Application).

To make it easier, there's a GUI tool named [Desktop Entry Creator](https://pypi.org/project/desktop-entry-creator/). It does all the work for you, and all you need to install it is `pip` and Python 3. I use it on my laptop and it works wonders! The only thing is it puts the resulting .desktop file in your **home .local folder**, meaning that if you want the Signal app icon to be added to all users' Dash, you are going to need to `sudo mv` it to the aforementioned folder!